# undefined function when triggering a onmouseover of a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting undefined function error. I have defined this function on onmouseover but it is not working.

My code is

**HTML**

```
<div class="col2" onmouseover="show_info('<?php echo $sub_menu['page_id'];  ?>');" onmouseout="hide_info();">
<a href="#">
<img src="css/images/img1.png" />
<h3><?php echo $sub_menu['page_title'];  ?></h3>
</a>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
        function show_info(id)
        {
        alert('hiiii');
        var data = "page_id ="+id;
        $.ajax({
        url:"get_page_info.php", type:"post",data=data,cache:false,
        success: function(html)
            {
            document.getElementById('hide').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=html;
            }
        });
        }

        function hide_info()
        {
            document.getElementById('hide').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('show').style.display='none';
        }
    </script>
```

Please suggest

Comment: Is this script block above the html code? If not, please move it and try.

Comment: instead of `function show_info(id){}` try `var show_info = function(id){}`

Comment: Please show your css and it is  best to create a jsfiddle. Why do you not implement the onmouseover/out using jQuery?

Comment: can you post your HTML source, I mean what you get after loading the PHP file.

Comment: Please try moving the script block above html code as suggested earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error here

```
url:"get_page_info.php", type:"post",data=data,cache:false,
```

Change it to

```
url:"get_page_info.php", type:"post",data:data,cache:false,
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2jcw/)

You also have a problem with your `data` declaration `"page_id ="+id;`. You mean `"page_id="+id;`, or indeed `var data = {page_id: id};`

**Here is how you would handle this using jQuery to avoid the problem completely.**

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G2jcw/1/)**

HTML - use a class and store the info in data.

```
<div class="col2 showinfo" data-showinfo="123"><h3>456</h3></div> 
<div id="show" style="display:none">show</div>
<div id="hide">hide</div>
```

So in your PHP this would read

```
<div class="col2 showinfo" data-showinfo="<?php echo $sub_menu['page_id']; ?>">
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $('.showinfo').hover(
        function(){ // first one is mouseover
            var data = {page_id: $(this).data('showinfo')};
            data.html="this is page " + data.page_id; // jsfiddle test
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url:"/echo/html/", // jsfiddle test
                type:"post",
                data:data,
                cache:false,
                success: function(html){
                    console.log(html);
                   $('#hide').toggle();
                   $('#show').toggle().html(html);
                }
            });            
        }, 
        function(){ // second one is mouseout
            $('#hide, #show').toggle();
        }
   );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the script in line  `7` there is a syntax error `data=data` must be `data:data`

Comment: make sure there is no errors before the show_info(id) decleration , or in the whole page will be better (take a look on the console of the browser if you're using chrome or firefox) - as Sherin said move it to the top of the page @RahulNarhe